# Как вывести AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

Мне надо по нажатию на кнопку в быстрых настройках (Tileservice) открыть AlertDialog, но его не открыть без активити, мне не надо, чтобы открывалось активити, просто AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания `AlertDialog` нужен контекст, а не активити.

Сам `TileService` является потомком `android.content.Context`, точно так же как и `Activity`.

Созданный диалог нужно показывать методом `TileService.showDialog(android.app.Dialog)`

Вот хорошая статья о `TileService` от разработчиков:
https://medium.com/google-developers/quick-settings-tiles-e3c22daf93a8

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, открывать AlertDialog без активити - это плохая практика, так не нужно делать. Если хотите, то вы можете попробовать создать активити и задать ему стиль диалогового окна:

В AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" 
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

Comment: Ответ неверный. Можно открыть и без `Activity` - нужен только `context`